# Tableview not loading data after popping View Controller

Tags: swift

When I pop the view controller stack, I need a table view in the first view controller to reload. I am using viewWillAppear (I already tried viewDidAppear and it didn't work).

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    print("will appear")
    loadData()
}
```

Once the view controller has re-appeared, I need to query the API again which I am doing in another service class with a completion handler of course and then reloading the table view:

```
@objc func loadData() {
    guard let userEmail = userEmail else { return }
    apiRequest(userId: userEmail) { (queriedArticles, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("error in API query: \(error)")
        } else {
            guard let articles = queriedArticles else { return }
            self.articlesArray.removeAll()
            self.articleTableView.reloadData()
            self.articlesArray.append(contentsOf: articles)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.articleTableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What happens is that I am able to pop the stack and see the first view controller BUT it has the same data as it did before. I expect there to be one more cell with new data and it doesn't appear. I have to manually refresh (using refresh control) to be able to query and load the new data.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Probably not related, but anyway you must call `super.viewWillAppear()` in your override

Comment: Forgot to mention. Yes I called super as well. Didn't help.

Comment: Is the cell you expect to be there being pulled from the API? It looks like you are trying to pull the same data when you call loadData().

Comment: Yes, it's being pulled from the API. Yes I pull the existing data + the new data and then reload the tableview.